# Link error when i try to compile an xll on VC2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, excel, linker, xll

I try to compile a xll (like a dll but for excel).

i follow this link : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178474/en-us

when i compile my dll, i have these following errors :

```
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _debugPrintf already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _GetTempMemory already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _FreeAllTempMemory already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _Excel already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _Excel12f already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempNum already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempNum12 already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempStr already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempStrConst already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempStr12 already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempBool already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempBool12 already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempInt already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempInt12 already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempErr already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempErr12 already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempActiveRef already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempActiveRef12 already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempActiveCell already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempActiveCell12 already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempActiveRow already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempActiveRow12 already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempActiveColumn already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempActiveColumn12 already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempMissing already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _TempMissing12 already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _InitFramework already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _QuitFramework already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _FreeXLOperT already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _FreeXLOper12T already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _ConvertXLRefToXLRef12 already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _ConvertXLRef12ToXLRef already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _XLOper12ToXLOper already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>frmwrk32.lib(FRAMEWRK.obj) : error LNK2005: _XLOperToXLOper12 already defined in FRAMEWRK.obj
1>Riskedge_Xll.exp : warning LNK4070: /OUT:Riskedge_Xll.xll directive in .EXP differs from output filename 'Riskedge_Xll.dll'; ignoring directive
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

i try to use `/NODEFAULTLIB` but the result is worse than before i modified it
Here you have my command line :

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\Stagiaire\Documents\Riskedge\Online_pricer\Xll Builder\Debug\Riskedge_Xll.dll"
/INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO 
/LIBPATH:"C:\Users\Stagiaire\Documents\Riskedge\Online_pricer\Xll Builder" 
/DLL "XLCALL32.LIB" "frmwrk32.lib" "User32.lib" /DEF:"C:\Users\Stagiaire\Documents\Riskedge\Online_pricer\Xll Builder\Riskedge_Xll.def" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Debug\Riskedge_Xll.dll.intermediate.manifest"
/ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
/DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Users\Stagiaire\Documents\Riskedge\Online_pricer\Xll Builder\Debug\Riskedge_Xll.pdb" 
/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /PGD:"C:\Users\Stagiaire\Documents\Riskedge\Online_pricer\Xll Builder\Debug\Riskedge_Xll.pgd" 
/TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

i try to compile on a Windows seven x64 under visual ultimate 2010

Anyone have an idea to solve my problem plz ?

Comment: Can you post your full linker command?

Comment: Of course, I posted it in my question

Comment: Do you have the framewrk sources (FRAMEWRK.c, FRAMEWRK.H, MemoryPool.h, etc) as part of your solution/project?

Comment: yes, all of these source files and header files are on my solution/project

Comment: I that is the case then you don't need to link with "frmwrk32.lib": "To use the Framework library functions, you must include the FRAMEWRK.H file in your C code and add the FRAMEWRK.C or FRMWRK32.LIB files to your code project." So, either FRAMEWRK.C or FRMWRK32.LIB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wvsprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is defined in `User32.lib`, so you must link with this library.

From [Functions in the Framework Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687863.aspx):

> To use the Framework library functions, you must include the FRAMEWRK.H file in your C code and add the FRAMEWRK.C or FRMWRK32.LIB files to your code project.

Either include `FRAMEWRK.c` in your project/solution or link with `FRMWRK32.LIB`, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favor and use http://xll.codeplex.com. You will be up and running in 2 minutes.